# Does Ubuntu periodically clean empty directories under /var/run?

Tags: default, cron, automatic

I've noticed that empty directories get deleted from `/var/run/` on reboot. I'm wondering if that's something Ubuntu does or something that I have installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/var/run` is a symlink on `/run` and that's just a `tmpfs` mount created on boot. Everything in it is stored in RAM and dies at reboot.

So things are already slightly different. I can't see anything about `tmpfs` being set up to autoclean other than on reboots though and I've just run through this:

```
sudo mkdir /run/pie
sudo touch /run/pie/pies
sudo rm /run/pie/pies
ls # /run/pie/ still exists, empty
```

So it might be just you - or it might be a cleanup daemon. I've had a quick search through `/etc` but can't find anything. You might have more luck: `sudo grep -R 'tmpfs' /etc/`

Comment: If it's tmpfs, it should get erased every time you turn off power, no?

Comment: Yes, that's how `/var/run` gets cleaned every time to answer my own question.

Comment: I actually answered that in the second sentence :P **Edit:** I see the confusion. I'm operating under the assumption you're seeing things disappear on a live system without restarting. If you're just rebooting and noticing things are gone, then yes, that's just the nature of tmpfs.